# 'Explode' Jquery Effect only showing left

Tags: jquery, height, explode, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery UI Accordion that I am attempting to 'Explode' on click using the JQuery effect. For some reason the effect only shows to the left. Any ideas?

```
$(this).effect('explode', { pieces: '50' }, 800);
```

Also, I am currently animating the height of the 'ui.newContent' at a fixed height of 200px as follows:

```
ui.newContent.delay(000).animate({ height: 200,'padding-top': 20,'padding-bottom': 20}, 700);
```

but what I need is to be able to animate the 'natural' full height of each content div.

I tried using:

```
var fullHeight = $(this).height()
```

but I wasn't able to get it working.

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ifthatdoesntdoit/Cb68E/10/

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the context of the code you've posted, it is difficult to offer much more info. Could you share an isolated example of the problem code on http://jsfiddle.net/? EDIT: I see you posted a jsfiddle a few seconds ago. Stand by!

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it, linqq.